# Need help to create CRUD screen with dropdown (relation) using yii-framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I need to create CRUD screen using yii-framework. Simple CRUD screen using one table is working perfectly fine. I'm facing problem/issue while using dropdown (linking table).

I have installed giix extension which is suppose to create CRUD with dropdown if FK is specified but I dnt have MySql Engine InnoDB on my hosting provider, so I'm not able to use that extension. I need to do it manually.

I have two tables

main:-
id
store_id
prefix

store:-
id
name

Now store_id of main is FK to id of store table. And I want to create CRUD for main table.

So that Add Screen should show:-

Store Name:- Dropdown
prefix:- Textbox

View screen should use name column of store table instead of showing store_id

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate CRUD using Gii, then read my blog. http://jmmurphy.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-yii-model-relations.html

Basically you will have something like this for your store_id field after Gii Generation

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'store_id'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'store_id', array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255));?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'store_id'); ?>
```

The textField line is replaced by:

```
<?php $list = CHtml::listData(Store::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'store_id', $list, array('empty'=>'(Select a Store)')); ?>
```

You also need to define relations in your Main model so that you can access related tables (even if your database does not support foreign keys) like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'store'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Store', 'store_id'),
    );
}
```

And to complete this relation, you should also add the following relation to your Store model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'main'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Main', 'store_id'),
    );
}
```

These relations define a One to Many relation between Store and Main where store is the parent, and Main is the Child.  To make it a One to One relationship change HAS_MANY to HAS_ONE.  The HAS_* goes in the parent model and points to the foreign key attribute in the child table.  The BELONGS_TO goes in the child and tells the attribute in the child table that points to the primary key in the parent.

Now to see the store name in the view action, you need to change 'store_id' in your view.php to an array that looks like:

```
array(
   'name' => 'store_id',
   'value' => $model->store->name,
)
```

The admin view is slightly different.  I am not sure exactly why, but to view the store name instead of the id in the admin view you will need to use an array that looks like:

```
array(
   'name' => 'store_id',
   'value' => '$data->store->name',
)
```

Note that Gii generates this so that $data is the model instead of $model, and also it does a funky double indirection thing so that you need to put the variable declaration in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks jmarkmurphy for reply and it is working perfectly fine when I click on Add but still on view form I'm able to see Id instead of name :(... I guess I need to modify _view.php file to see store name instead of id..here is code of _view.php:-

<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('store_id')); ?>:</b>
 <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->store_id); ?>

Can u plz let me know what should I replace above code with?

Comment: No relation name because i dont have InnoDB storage in MySql... I just replaced the code which u given me and it is working on Add screen.. I'm able to see dropdown on Add screen but on view screen of single record... or grid screen.. I'm seeing store id instead of store name

Comment: Excellent... Thanks a lot jmarkmurphy :)... It is working and worked perfectly..exactly what I wanted... I modified view.php and now it is working fine... I'm able to see store name on view page

But what about admin.php (which is grid view):-

There code is:-

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'main-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  'id',
  'store_id',
  'prefix',
  'suffix',
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
)); ?>

And what about _view.php where code is:-

<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->store_id); ?>

Comment: Sorry to ask so many questions and queries :(..Actually I'm newbie in yii framework and I need to do this CRUD task :(... I seriously don't know how this works :(

Comment: Well, you should be comforted to know that Yii is very easy to learn, and has decent documentation.  I am new to it as well, as in I have not yet completed my first Yii project.  A few places that I go to look first are the class reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView (for GridView), and the definitive guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/. these two places help me a lot.  I also have a blog where I have put a few tidbits that I have learned.  I hope to continue writing about it as I go along: http://jmmurphy.blogspot.com/.

Comment: I gave you admin.  Try to figure our _view on your own.  You now have enough information.  Also, you should mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Accepted as correct answer :)..thanks for help :).. But I seriously dnt know how to do it on grid page :(
Will try to do it at my own :(

Comment: What have you tried, what happened, and where have you looked for resolution?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for help. My application is now working. Thanks from bottom of my heart to post solution :). God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jmarkmurphy for your help. You helped me lot and I have marked your answer as correct only as you gave me guidance. Just posting exact code in detail.

I changed view.php with below code:-

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'store.name',
    'prefix',
),
```

));

Also changed admin.php with below code:-

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->store->name); ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'main-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'store.name',
    'prefix',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

Thanks once again jmarkmurphy. Thanks a lot . My application is now working and exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: Check your labels.  The reason I use the array rather than the short cut store.name is that it will guess at a label if it doesn't find the exact attribute in the labels array.  That means I have to add a label for each shortcut that I use, or I have to accept the guesses for the ones I don't add.  So if your labels are not quite what you expected, you need to add a label for store.name.

Comment: Sir you are genius. You are absolutely correct regarding labels. It was not showing proper label. It was showing "Name" as label while I wanted label to be Store Name. Changed the code to what you have mentioned:-

array(
   'name' => 'store_id',
   'value' => $model->store->name,
),

Now it is showing proper label. Thanks a lot :)